# Searching for a component in NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, controls, .net-3.5

I'm searching for a component similiar to this one(Delphi) in .NET 3.5 SP1

[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/6657/compc.jpg](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/6657/compc.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView with "View = Detail" or DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your precise application, you might also want to look at PropertyGrid (in addition to TcKs answer).

Answer (score 0):

Aye, [ListView using Detail View](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/MultiColumnListViewControl04252005023924AM/MultiColumnListViewControl.aspx) is the way to go.